# Selenium IDE not finding element

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

We're just doing a POC with Selenium and I'm working with the Selenium-IDE on Firefox 54. We plan to use Webdriver ultimately.

I recorded a test at home at weekend and the first 20-ish steps worked. Emailed myself the HTML and pasted into IDE source tab at work. Didn't work at all.

Recorded a brand new test at work. Always fails with the following, but the page (login screen) loads in less than second and the element is there.

> [error] Element id=txtUsername not found

Here's my test

```
<table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" border="1">
<thead>
<tr><td rowspan="1" colspan="3">New Test</td></tr>
</thead><tbody>
<tr>
    <td>open</td>
    <td>/MISConsoleUAT/login.aspx</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>waitForPageToLoad</td>
    <td>10000</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>id=txtUsername</td>
    <td>mark-a</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>id=txtPassword</td>
    <td>test</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>id=Submit1</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
```

I tried wait for element visible and a bunch of other waits, but i can't find the element.

any ideas?

Comment: Can you share the DOM of the page you are trying to automate for? Also,  IDE recorded steps fails for most of the time when run via script or replayed.
http://www.helloselenium.com/2013/04/wait-for-element-in-selenium-ide.html see this has more detail on how to add execute IDE steps.

Comment: it works on my pc at home, so I know the script is good and I'm connecting to exactly same page at work. DOM is huge and has a lot of confidentail data in it

Comment: Are you using the same browser and version?  Not sure what waits you have tried, but it's possible the page isn't loaded completely (even if you can see it on the screen, there may be other things loading that you can't).  If I'm looking for a specific element, I usually use a 
Wait For Element Present command for that specific element.  You might also try re-recording that specific step and in the IDE see if there are different targets for that element besides the one you're using.

Comment: @Klendathu - yes 100% same and I do have wait for. As you can see in original post: 10 sec wait for load. the page loads in less than a second

Comment: Are you able to give us the URL you're testing? or paste the HTML source for the part of the page in question?

Comment: @Klendathu unfortunately I can;t share the URL. Posting the HTML won;t help. The script works from my home PC but doesn;t on my work PC - it's exact same URL. If it was a problem with the script it wouldnt; work from home